# Rails form grab value of form element in submit confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I use a `form_tag` in rails and in my `submit` tag I want to have the confirmation say:

Are you sure you want to submit XXX?

With XXX being the value of a form element. I have a unique identifier for that form field and I can use jquery's `$("#...").val()` to get it but how do I execute that in the `submit` tag's `data:{ confirm: "Are you sure you want to submit ___?"}` code? or do I just need to drop that and do a manual bit of javascript code and bind it to the `onclick` event?

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out.

The `button_tag` has an `onclick: "return myfunc(\"#{uniqIdentifier}\");"`. The function is pretty simple:

```
function myfunc(value){

  return confirm("Are you sure you want to submit + $("#"+value).val() + "?")

}
```